# How do i sort the given program by frequency? [In ascending order]

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that asks for the input of the file and arrange the files by frequencies, that is the words that appear the most in the file appear first. This is what I have done so far. But I cannot figure out how to arrange them by frequencies.

```
#Ask the user to input the name of the file. 
text = input("Please enter the name of the file:")
#Open the corresponding file
file=open(text,'r')

# Create an empty dictionary 
Dictionary = dict() 
  
# Loop through each line of the file 
for line in file: 
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
    line = line.strip()  
    line = line.upper() 
  
    # Split the line into words 
    words = line.split(" ") 
  
#Iterate over each word in line 
    for word in words: 
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
        if word in Dictionary: 
            # Increment count of word by 1 
            Dictionary[word] =Dictionary[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            Dictionary[word] = 1
  
# Print the contents of dictionary 
for key in list (Dictionary.keys()): 
    print(key, ":", Dictionary[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the dictionary a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); it works similarly to a `dict`, but it also has the `most_common()` method which does exactly what you want.

```
Dictionary = collections.Counter() 

...

for word, count in Dictionary.most_common():
    print(word, ":", count)
```

As a side-benefit, you will no longer need to check whether a word is already in the dictionary; you can just write `Dictionary[word] += 1` and the `Counter` will automatically start from 0 for words that haven't been seen before

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the dictionary in reverse before printing?

```
for key in list (dict(sorted(Dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))): 
    print(key, ":", Dictionary[key])
```